# HTTP POST function

Tags: ios, swift, http-post

I'm trying to use a POST function to take text from a label and send it as an email. The problem is, whenever I try and use the text from the label, the only data in the email is `[]`

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Code:

```
 func postToServerFunction() {
        var userText : String = labelText.text!
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.webaddress.com/email_test.php")!
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        var bodyData = userText
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
            {
                (response, data, error) in
                println(response)

        }
    }
```

Edit:

With this code I now get {""} in the email:

```
func postToServerFunction() {
    var emailText = labelText
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http:www.webaddress.com/email_test.php")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    var bodyData = "\(emailText)"
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            println(response)

    }
}
```

Comment: "Data" probably contains the response data to the request. Probably check that by converting to string

Comment: I'm pretty new to swift, are you able to show me how?

Answer (score 0):

This API is deprecated in iOS9. Probably the easiest way to do this is by using Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

If you still wanted to use this API, then you should use the 'data' object.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        let strData = String(data, NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(strData)
    }
```

so this way you are initiating string instance from the NSData returned.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `NSURLConnection`, as noted by other it's deprecated. If you don't want to depend on external libraries (Alamofire) use `NSURLSession` instead.

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.webaddress.com/email_test.php")  else {
  print("bad url")
  return
}

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration())
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = "Some Text".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let post = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

    guard let data = data, let response = response where error == nil else {
        print("Connection error")
        return
    }

    let strData = String(data, NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(strData)
}

post.resume()
```

Comment: for `guard` yes, but you can also use conditional binding `if let something = ...` in swift 1.x

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was away. I tried your code but can still only have [] in the email body. Any solutions you can think of? @tmpz

Comment: Have you checked the response value? What is data you're getting back? This seems like a problem with your  email_test.php

Comment: I'm getting `(<41727261 790a280a 290a>, 4)` returned back when I run it. I'm also getting an error on `let response = response`. Specifically the first response in that snippet. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Hard to tell, what kind of error are you having? Also print both data and response.statusCode

Comment: Sorry, stuffed up with error. I've fixed it. Here's the data i'm getting back now: `<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7feca382de80> { URL: http://www.webaddress.com/email_test.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 30;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 25 Jan 2016 23:15:28 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=100";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
(<41727261 790a280a 290a>, 4)`

Comment: You reckon this could be a server side problem then? Thanks for the help :) @tmpz

Comment: What you are doing is correct, that' is the way a post is made. Maybe you want to add the "Content-Encoding" header to specify what encoding the body is in. This varies on your needs.